# Integer vs. String decision making in Java

Tags: java, string, integer

I'm working on a program where user input is an array of mixed Strings and Integers. For Example:

dog 10 23 cat frog 22 elephant

I'm supposed to sort this array without changing the type of each index. So the output  will be;

cat 10 22 dog elephant 23 frog

After reading the line from the console, I'm using a string tokenizer to go through each element. After that I'm trying to parseInt and if it throws an exception, I'm assuming that it is a string, otherwise it is an Integer. Is there a better way to figure out if a token is numerical or not?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relying on exceptions for program logic is considered poor practice because exceptions are slow. Instead, you can use regular expressions.

```
Matcher numericalMatcher = Pattern.compile("^-?\\d+$").matcher(token);
if( numericalMatcher.matches() ) {
   // Token is a number
} else {
   // Token is not a number
}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Comment: +1 About not relying on exceptions in normal program flow. @Mehmet: If you want to allow for negative numbers, throw a `-?` after the `^` at the beginning of the regex (which means "zero or one `-` characters").

Comment: I disagree.  Exceptions are slow, but don't optimize until you need to.  I'd write an `isNumber` private static method and use a try/parseInt/catch block for its implementation.  Easy enough to swap it out if it is too slow.

Comment: @KeithRandall: It's not optimization. If you're going to write `isNumber`, why not write it properly in the first place? If there were any significant work involved, absolutely, don't optimize prematurely although I'd be *very* leery of using exceptions in more than 50% of normal program flow (per examples from the OP). But here there just isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Using `parseInt` is not a bad idea.

Alternatively you can use a regular expression but I believe your choice is more practical and simple.

Comment: *"...more practical and fast"* Not faster, no. All of those exceptions caused by the non-numeric input as a *normal* case...

Comment: I check on my machine, regex is about 5 times faster then parseInt. I can parse 1 million of strings in 780 millis with parseInt and in 140 millis. So if you have to check few values I would use parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example use 'StringUtils.isNumeric' to detect if a string is numerical

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

The drawback is that you have to include a library.